# how to z-normalise time series?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, normalization, standardization, z-score

Suppose I have 1000 samples of time series, every one of which has 150 points.(If sample frequency is 150 Hz, then every one of the time series stands for 1s.)What is the correct way to z-normalise them? I can think up of two possible ways as follows.

1. For every series, calculate its mean and standard deviation, then do a linear transformation
   $z_i = (x_i−mean) / std$.
2. For every dimension in the time series (150 dimension in a series), calculate the mean of the very dimension of 1000 time series, and the standard deviation as well. Then do a linear transformation to this dimension.

In some blogs, I saw that the author tends to choose the second method. But wouldn't this method twist the wave form of time series and distort the correlation between the neighborhood?

I encounter this problem in machine learning when I try to build a classifier to tell whether there is a P300 in a piece of EEG. After the normalization, the time series would be fed into a artifitial neural network.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: If you spell out precisely why you want to standardize in this way, you would be a long way to answering your own question. Which variability do you want to scale away? Note that standardizing doesn't affect correlations, as such. Indeed the correlation is the mean product of standardized variables. (Terminology is a beast: statistically minded people tend to call (value $-$ mean) / SD standardization and often avoid the term "normalise" because it can refer so many different things. I can't speak for machine learning people at all, but their usages often seem to differ.)

Comment: 0. Welcome to the CV community. 1. As Nick mentioned (+1) it is unclear what you are trying to achieve. In general if we assume that our sample of 1000 time-series reflects 1000 realisations of the same stochastic process $S$ it would make sense to subtract the longitudinal (time-varying) mean and standardised by the subsequent (time-varying) standard deviation of that process $S$.